# Parse SOAP response into ListBox error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, soap, listbox

I am making a Windows Phone Application with SOAP services. I want to parse the XML response into a ListBox, but I've got multiple errors.

Here is all my code and log:

**Verkopen.xaml**

```
(...)    
<ListBox Height="601" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" DataContext="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="Sample" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding omschr}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding totalen}" ></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
(...)
```

**Verkopen.xaml.cs**

```
    (...)
     class XMLInfo
        {
            public string omschr { get; set; }
            public string totalen { get; set; }
        }
    (...)
private void ophalencompleet(object sender, SalesService.retSalesCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
     string XMLResponse = e.Result;
                var XResult = XElement.Parse(XMLResponse);

                var result = XResult.Descendants("Table").Select(t => new XMLInfo
        {
            omschr = t.Descendants("omschr").First().Value,
            totalen = t.Descendants("exclusief").First().Value,
        });

                foreach (var res in result)
                {
                    string omschr = res.omschr; // here i am able get the response
                    Debug.WriteLine("Wat in de tabel zou moeten: " + omschr);
                    string totalen = res.totalen;
                }

                listBox1.ItemsSource = result;
    (...)
```

**SOAP Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <expnr>672 </expnr>
    <artnr>GX-05           </artnr>
    <omschr>Glaswerk OP=OP                </omschr>
    <datum>2013-09-30T00:00:00+02:00</datum>
    <aantal>1</aantal>
    <exclusief>2.44</exclusief>
    <inclusief>2.95</inclusief>
    <loca_id>0490</loca_id>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <expnr>672 </expnr>
    <artnr>LZ03-0008       </artnr>
    <omschr>Pot RH 50x15x24,5 zwart       </omschr>
    <datum>2013-09-30T00:00:00+02:00</datum>
    <aantal>1</aantal>
    <exclusief>20.62</exclusief>
    <inclusief>24.95</inclusief>
    <loca_id>0490</loca_id>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Errors:**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'omschr' value (type 'System.String') from 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (type 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo'). BindingExpression: Path='omschr' DataItem='CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (HashCode=241995340); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: CtrlBase.XMLInfo.get_omschr()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] inA first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'totalen' value (type 'System.String') from 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (type 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo'). BindingExpression: Path='totalen' DataItem='CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (HashCode=241995340); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: CtrlBase.XMLInfo.get_totalen()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[]A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'omschr' value (type 'System.String') from 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (type 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo'). BindingExpression: Path='omschr' DataItem='CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (HashCode=241995360); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: CtrlBase.XMLInfo.get_omschr()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] inA first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'totalen' value (type 'System.String') from 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (type 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo'). BindingExpression: Path='totalen' DataItem='CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (HashCode=241995360); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: CtrlBase.XMLInfo.get_totalen()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[]A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'omschr' value (type 'System.String') from 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (type 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo'). BindingExpression: Path='omschr' DataItem='CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (HashCode=241995377); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: CtrlBase.XMLInfo.get_omschr()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] inA first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'totalen' value (type 'System.String') from 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (type 'CtrlBase.XMLInfo'). BindingExpression: Path='totalen' DataItem='CtrlBase.XMLInfo' (HashCode=241995377); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: CtrlBase.XMLInfo.get_totalen()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[]The program '[267518466] UI Task: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Who can help me to fix this. I've searched Google a lot, but didn't find the fix.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The class `XMLInfo` must be public.

Comment: @ToniPetrina It must be "Public Class" ?

Comment: Yes, because if it is internal, Windows Phone 7 reflection cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this issue in a blog post, check it out [here](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/data-binding-windows-phone-7-cannot-access-privateinternal-functions-but-windows-phone-8-can/).

The problem lies within the reflection API on the Windows Phone 7. It is interesting that the code above will work if WP7 app is run on Windows Phone 8 device or emulator since on WP8 you *can* access private/internal stuff.

If you ever run into data binding issues, check if the class and/or properties are public. And try running the code in debug mode with break-on-thrown-exceptions enabled.